# How to add icon into div menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Since the menu I've created is different, I can't seem to figure out an appropriate tag/place to set up an icon. I've attempted different solutions, but it messed up the rest of the css in the menu.

This is what I would like to use as an "image" temporally. Would like to learn what I can do to make this menu better to support the icons.

```
display: block;
background-color: red;
width: 20px;
height: 20px
```

Once a solution has been found, I will replace the

```
background-color: red;
```

with

```
background-image: url(image_directory.png);
background-repeat: none;
```

Trying to add an image icon to the left of the text (LOGIN, REGISTER, LOST PASSWORD?)

```js
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebar_menu .dropbtn").click(function() {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#menu_container {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
#sidebar_menu {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sidebar_menu #login_picture {}
/* Style The Dropdown Button */

#sidebar_menu .dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 226px;
  outline: none;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: static;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu_container">
  <div id="sidebar_menu">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div id="login_picture" class="dropbtn">LOGIN</div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Website Login Box Display Here</a>
      </div>
      <div id="register_picture" class="dropbtn">REGISTER</div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Register Here</a>
      </div>
      <div id="password_picture" class="dropbtn">LOST PASSWORD?</div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Get Password Here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use different colors to make it easier to understand, so hopefully it help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :before to archive it.

```
.dropbtn:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05axmr2b/)

Comment: I've never seen that ":before", before. Thanks! How can I center the text vertically? Would I need to rewrite the HTML better? (<a><span> tags)

Comment: @VisualizeEdits There many method to archive it, e.g. [jsfiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/05axmr2b/2/)

Comment: That look amazing! I experimented with some different ways while understanding how it work now. How should I change the pictures of each button? I was thinking of something like this.
 #login_picture .dropbtn:before {
 background-color: aqua;
}

#register_picture .dropbtn:before {
 background-color: orange;
 
#password_picture .dropbtn:before {
 background-color: purple;
}

Answer (score 0):

to add an icon as a background you can use :

```
    background: url('http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/131/131974.png') no-repeat blue 90% center;
    background-size: 20px;
```

the url is your image file and background-size is just for this exemple.

Comment: The only problem is, I don't have it set up to place that icon next to the text in the menu. Should I make another div or something similar and place it inside the (dropbtn)?

I created an example of where I'm trying to place it in the html.
<div id="login_picture" class="dropbtn">LOGIN</div>